# How to get size of underlying stream when count and limit is used?

Tags: java, java-8

I have a rather large java.util.stream.Stream, and I would like to extract a subset of this stream as well as get the size of the entire source stream. I would like to retain the stream behavior, so I do not want to collect this stream to a List. Is this possible ?

```
Stream src = ....
Stream subsetStream = src.offset(x).limit(y);
long totalLengthOfSrc = ??
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Count is a terminal operation, meaning that the stream is considered consumed afterwards - so it's impossible to use limit on it. I don't think this is possible using the straightforward stream API, but you could do it like this:

```
final AtomicLong length = new AtomicLong(0);
Stream subsetStream = src.filter(a -> length.getAndIncrement() < y);
```

length could be a regular long instead, if you're certain that src isn't a parallel stream. If src is a parallel stream whose length is larger than y, then you might not get the first y elements but some y elements.

Comment: limit is not a terminal operation.

Comment: `length` cannot be a regular `long` as you can’t modify local variables of a lambda expression’s surrounding scope. However, this solution doesn’t work in parallel with ordered streams, regardless of whether you use `AtomicLong` or any other `long` holding container.

Comment: @Holger yes you need some sort of holder for the long.

Answer (score -1):

In general - yes, it is possible. It depends on what Stream exactly do you use. Stream is just an interface, while your object is always an instance of a certain class. FileInputStream, for example, has associated FileChannel that can be accessed via getChannel() method and has the size() method.

Comment: `FileInputStream` doesn't implement `Stream`.

Comment: OP is talking about `java.util.stream.Stream` Interface.